# Why viewWillTransition method call in all view controllers when rotate the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode9, uiviewanimationtransition

My application is tab based navigation. I am using Xcode9 with iOS11. For support landscape/portrait compatibility I am using the following method in my all viewControllers.

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

}
```

But when I rotate the app in first view controller, then automatically call the **viewWillTransition** method in all other view controllers. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It's calling the `viewWillTransition` method because all the tab view controllers are in the memory at that time.

You can add a check for the current view controller and update it only when it's the right view controller.

Make a boolean value true when `viewWillAppear` method is called and make it false when `viewWillDisappear` method will be called.